# Hiren boot CD is not booting when I connected with HDD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

A computer in my organization is not booting. In BIOS sometimes it showed disk error and I restarted several times. Sometimes it's working and sometimes it's not.

Suddenly today it stopped working and not booting at all. I'm trying to boot a live CD and copy the content. I thought of trying to repair bad sectors but it's not at  booting. When I boot hiren's boot cd from USB it is stuck at loading screen for a long time. When I remove the HDD and boot the hiren's boot CD, it working.

I can't connect HDD to motherboard and boot hiren's boot CD.

I tried with other hard disks and it worked fine. It booted with the HDD connected to motherboard.

What should be the problem ?

HDD is detecting in BIOS BTW.

Comment: The hard drive has died. Get the Manufacturer's Hardware Test application and run that. This will confirm the status of the drive.

Comment: Do you hear the drive spin up?

Comment: Hirens is off topic here.

Comment: @John's comment would be the recommended way to go, with `smartctl` doing the same, however, if trying to boot anything results in a hang, and disconnecting the HDD resolves the hang, it's a definite hardware fault on the HDD. To run the S.M.A.R.T tests, disconnect the HDD before booting, plugging it back in before testing, which will allow booting without a hangtime from the system's inability to access the HDD. If the HDD is under warranty, print off the output of `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`, which will show the hardware fault, to send with the drive.

Comment: You might have a bad line somewhere, data link, power cord. Might need it opened and check all the lines. Retry in BIOS after you replace and/or reset the lines to the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind 
it just took much time to load the os or hiren's boot from the pendrive.
The read speeds are very low i thought it stuck in the screen.